# Cannot Set Boolean Field in new Netsuite Record

Tags: php, netsuite

I am trying to use the Netsuite PHP Toolkit to create a new task, assign it to an employee and have an email sent to that employee.

I can successfully create and assign the task, but can't get the email to send.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    $task_data = array(
        'title'=>$request['subject'],
        'assigned'=>new nsRecordRef(array('internalId'=>NETSTUITE_CONF::EMPLOYEE_ID, 'type'=>'employee')),
        'message'=>$request['body'],
        'sendEmail'=>true,
        'startDate'=>date('c', strtotime($request['date_added']))
    );
    $task = new nsComplexObject('Task', $task_data);
    $ret = $ns->add($task);
    var_dump($ret);
```

Which outputs:

```
object(nsWriteResponse)#13 (3) {
  ["isSuccess"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["statusDetail"]=>
  NULL
  ["recordRef"]=>
  object(nsRecordRef)#19 (4) {
    ["nsComplexObject_type"]=>
    string(9) "RecordRef"
    ["nsComplexObject_namespace"]=>
    string(49) "urn:core_2010_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
    ["nsComplexObject_fields"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "task"
      ["internalId"]=>
      string(6) "408557"
    }
    ["nsComplexObject_namespaces"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

The new task has all the data set except the `sendEmail` field, which the SuiteTalk Schema Browser list the type as `xsd:boolean`.  I have tried sending the strings "true" and "T" as well, but the field remains false.

How can I set the field to `true`, so that the email is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from a netsuite employee on their support forum saying:

> Adding a task record via web services does not currently support
>   sending of the email when sendemail=true

Answer (score -1):

Try 'T' or 'F'  I just did that on a different boolean field elsewhere in netsuite and that's what did the trick for me.

Comment: No luck, the field is false either way.